# Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor (when declaring new variables in typescript)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

```
export class Patient {

  icNumber: string;
  fullname: string;
  password: string;
  birthday: Date;
  gender: string;
  address: string;
  email: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
  emergencyContactNumber: string;
  emergencyRelationship: string;
  height: number;
  weight: number;
}
```

[image: typescript errors: no initializers]

All lines have the same error.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Either initialize them in some way, or turn off strictPropertyInitialization in your config.

Comment: Or just don't make it a class, given it has no behaviour.